# Ubuntu 18.04, Unable to connect to internet using Wifi

Tags: networking, 18.04, internet, dns

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 which was working fine all this while. All of sudden I can no longer connect to the internet from any Wifi device but I can connect using USB tethering from a cellphone.

When I try to load a page using my Wifi connection. I get these two screens

[image]

[image]

**I tried to ping google but that also didn't work.**

```
~$ ping google.com
ping: google.com: Name or service not known


~$ ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.43.1 icmp_seq=7 Destination Net Unreachable
From 192.168.43.1 icmp_seq=50 Destination Net Unreachable
From 192.168.43.1 icmp_seq=93 Destination Net Unreachable
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
119 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 120740ms
```

**Wifi connection details**

[image]

This happened before as well when I upgraded Ubuntu 16 to 18, it was solved back then and I don't remember how. I tried all possible things I found on internet but nothing seems to solve this time.

If any additional information regrading any configuration is required then do comment, I will add.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu.  Based on the Wifi connection details, you seem to be connected to your router.  Have you tried re-starting your router?

Comment: Notice the ping replies came from the router, not 8.8.8.8. I agree with @JuanAntonio, I think the wireless is properly connected to the router but that the router is not connected to the internet. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.